# how can i redirect to specific link out of my app when devise before_filter :authenticate_user works

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

here is my categories controller code

```
   class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

     before_filter :authenticate_user! ,:except => :index

     def index
       #some code
     end

     def show
       #some code
     end

   end
```

clearly you can see my categories#index page are publicly view-able on which all categories are listed. When anyone click on category name without sign in, he/she will be redirect to 'localhost:3000/users/sign_in'.

but i want that user will be redirect to some url like "www.facebook.com" whenever devise before_filter :authenticate_user! work.

how i can achieve this?